# How to automatically register open generic interface with Castle Windsor?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container, open-generics, castle-windsor-3

I need to automatically register my open generic interface to its implementation classes 
My interface is something like that IIntegrationEventHandler

```
public interface IIntegrationEventHandler<in TIntegrationEvent> 
    where TIntegrationEvent : BaseIntegrationEvent
{
    Task HandleAsync(TIntegrationEvent @event);
}
```

My handlers will be something like that

```
    public class EmployeeEventsHandler : IIntegrationEventHandler<EmployeeUserCreated>
{
    public async Task HandleAsync(EmployeeUserCreated @event)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }        
}
```

Is there any general way in Castle Windsor to do such registration without manually do it with every handler, i searched a lot but nothing **note that i don't have a base handler class, only the generic interface and the implementation classes**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registration by conventions should work here:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("YourHandlersAssemblyName")
    .BasedOn(typeof(IIntegrationEventHandler<>))
    .WithServiceFirstInterface());

var handler = container.Resolve<IIntegrationEventHandler<EmployeeUserCreated>>();
```

Comment: Hi @jan, Thanks for your reply, Yes it works but the proxy resolved object didn't work properly

Comment: @yo2011, then you should edit your question to show what you mean.

Comment: Hi @jan , Your answer is what i am looking for but when i try to execute my handler, i got an error "Object disposed"

Comment: Thanks, i solved the issue and your solution works properly

Comment: To be more explicit (and avoid ambiguity in case your classes implement more than one interface I'd suggest a small tweak to use `.WithServiceBase()` instead